# Galaxy s2 stuck on samsung logo after installing an app

Tags: boot-loop

I installed a game on my Samsung galaxy s2 using an .apk file. 
I was playing a while, and after a couple of minutes my phone rebooted and got bootlooped. 
Now there is no boot-loop anymore, but it stucks on Samsung logo.

- I can get into Recovery mode/Download mode.
- My phone has a "PhilZ Touch 5" recovery.

How can I revive my phone?

Comment: Flash a `nandroid` backup? Install a new ROM?

Comment: Isn't there a simpler solution?

Comment: You could do a Factory Reset. Bootloops mean you will lose data. ALWAYS BACKUP everything! Nandroid backup and Titanium Backup!

Answer (score 1):

The usual way of fixing bootloops is doing a Factory Reset (via Recovery mode). Of course, you will lose your data.

But seeing that you have a custom recovery, do you also have a custom ROM installed? If yes, try (dirty) flashing the custom ROM via custom recovery. Don't forget to wipe cache and Dalvik cache.

Comment: Can't I just uninstall the problematic app somehow?

Comment: @OmerEldan Are you on a custom ROM?

Comment: Yes, but I don't remember the exact ROM name and version. @geffchang

Comment: @OmerEldan To uninstall, you can probably delete it from the /data/app folder via recovery. You can try, but I'm not sure if it'll work. Can you check?

Comment: @OmerEldan The newly installed app and its data is not necessarily what got corrupted.  If you need the phone to be usable a.s.a.p., in recovery do a nandroid backup and wipe data/factory reset. You can worry about getting your data out of nandroid's .tar backups later.

Comment: @Chahk Unfortunatly I cannot get into recovry mode now. What should I do?

Comment: @OmerEldan Can you get into Download mode? If so, you'll need to flash Samsung's stock image via Odin.

Comment: @Chahk Yea, I can. Will I lose my data if I'll flash a stock ROM ?

Comment: @OmerEldan Yes, Odin wipes all user data. Unfortunately without a functioning recovery image there is no way to backup the data.  You may want to try flashing only the custom recovery first to see if that will allow you to boot into recovery. Galaxy S2 section of XDA-developers forums should have the recoveries in Odin format. Be sure to download for your exact phone model, as there were quite a few variants under the "Galaxy S II" branding.

Comment: @Chahk I tried to flash stock rom via odin and it failed: <ID:0/008> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/008> Initialzation..
<ID:0/008> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/008> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/008> zImage
<ID:0/008> NAND Write Start!! 
<ID:0/008> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)

Comment: @OmerEldan Make sure the USB drivers are good. 99% of all Odin failures are because of bad drivers. Uninstall all current Galaxy S2 drivers (including Kies if you have it) then download and install the latest ones, and try flashing again.